# Does CloudFormation's "create-change-set" feature allow to separate planning from execution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, terraform

When deciding between [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) and [AWS CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/), one advantage generally associated with Terraform is the separation of planning ([`terraform plan`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/plan.html)) and execution ([`terraform apply`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/apply.html)).

I recently heard about CloudFormation's [create-change-set](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-change-set.html) feature, which is described as:

> Creates a list of changes that will be applied to a stack so that you can review the changes before executing them.

In [Updating Stacks Using Change Sets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-updating-stacks-changesets.html) from the AWS documentation, they describe the recommended update process.

Now I wonder:

- Doesn't create-change-set also allow to separate planning from execution?
- If not, what are the shortcomings in comparison with Terraform's plan & apply?

---

Background: Examples where the separation is emphasized as a significant advantage:

[Official comparison on terraform.io](https://www.terraform.io/intro/vs/cloudformation.html):

> Terraform also separates the planning phase from the execution phase, by using the concept of an execution plan. By running terraform plan, the current state is refreshed and the configuration is consulted to generate an action plan. The plan includes all actions to be taken: which resources will be created, destroyed or modified. It can be inspected by operators to ensure it is exactly what is expected.
>   [...]
>   Terraform lets operators apply changes with confidence, as they know exactly what will happen beforehand.

(Possibly outdated) [Blog post from 2014](https://ypoonawala.wordpress.com/2014/12/14/terraform-vs-cloudformation-a-comparison-of-infra-management-tools/) comparing Terraform and CloudFormation:

> Infrastructure Updates: This is the absolute killer feature of Terraform. Terraform has a separate planning and execution phase. The planning phase shows which resources will be created, modified and destroyed. It gives you complete control of how your changes will affect the existing environment, which is quite crucial. This was one of the main reasons why we went ahead with Terraform. CloudFormation does not show you what changes it is going to make to the environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CloudFormation Change Set is an analogous object to a Terraform plan saved in a plan file. Its core functionality is the same: inspect a report of the changes required to reach a new desired state, and then apply those changes.

When Terraform was originally created, CloudFormation did not have this feature. The documentation you have found was accurate at the time it was written, but with [the release of Change Sets](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-change-sets-for-aws-cloudformation/) there is not a significant difference in this regard.

The other difference covered in the official comparison still applies, however:

> Terraform similarly uses configuration files to detail the
>   infrastructure setup, but it goes further by being both cloud-agnostic
>   and enabling multiple providers and services to be combined and
>   composed. For example, Terraform can be used to orchestrate an AWS and
>   OpenStack cluster simultaneously, while enabling 3rd-party providers
>   like Cloudflare and DNSimple to be integrated to provide CDN and DNS
>   services. This enables Terraform to represent and manage the entire
>   infrastructure with its supporting services, instead of only the
>   subset that exists within a single provider. It provides a single
>   unified syntax, instead of requiring operators to use independent and
>   non-interoperable tools for each platform and service.